# Exceptions to the "Command-Query Separation" Rule?

Tags: ruby, command-query-separation

[Command-Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) "states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both. In other words, asking a question should not change the answer."

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
last = a.pop
```

Here, in Ruby, the `pop` command returns the item is popped off the Array.

This an example of a command *and* query within one method, and it seems necessary for it to be so.

If this is the case, is it really a code smell to have a method that is essentially a query as well as a command?

Comment: Personally, I think that because people expect `pop` on a stack to return the value it takes off the top of the stack, making two methods would just confuse and create chaos. Really, who wants to write `last = a.peek; a.pop` instead of `last = a.pop` just for theoretical "clarity". If you ask me, go with what's actually clearer and makes more sense. Programming clearly isn't an exact science.

Answer (score 4):

Stack popping is a well-known exception to CQS.  [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) notes it as a good place to break the rule.

I would say *in this case* it's not a code smell, but in general it *is* a code smell.